# Why repeated squaring and scaling a graph adjacency matrix yields a rank 1 projector?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, markov-chains, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

I've found an interesting relation between the equilibrium distribution of a random walker on a binary undirected graph and the repeated operation of squaring and scaling of its adjacency matrix.

Let $\mathbf{A}_0 \in \{0,1\}$ be a $n\times n$ adjacency matrix of a graph with $n$ nodes and $m$ links. Let $k_i$ be the degree of node $i$: clearly it must be $2m= \sum_i k_i$.

We now define the recurrency for $r=\{0,1,\ldots,\infty \}$:

$$\mathbf{A}_{r+1} = \frac{\mathbf{A}^2_{r}}{\textrm{Tr}[\mathbf{A}_{r}^2]}$$

Moreover, from graph theory we know that the following matrix $\mathbf{P}$ is called the *configuration model*:

$$\mathbf{P}=\frac{\mathbf{k}\mathbf{k}^T}{2m}$$

is a rank 1 matrix and interestingly it encodes the equilibrium distribution of a random walker diffusing on the network.

Strangely you can observe numerically in a variety of graphs that the following relation holds:

$$2m \mathbf{A}_{\infty} = \mathbf{P}$$

As far as I've observed this relation is general in the case the degree distribution is unimodal, it is true for the ER graph which has a binomial degree distribution and for regular graphs with a delta degree distribution.
However as long as you introduce a bimodal degree distribution this relation ceases to be exact.

I can imagine this property has something to do with the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ but cannot find any indication in the literature about repeated adjacency matrix squaring.

Is there someone here that can give me some hint?

Here I enclose some MATLAB code, too, you can find the `randomGraph.m` function [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9cf80a1ed200a55e703ca25cb6096592):

```
N=200;
p=0.25;
A = randomGraph(N,p);
% Compute the graph degrees
k = sum(A)';
% Compute the rank 1 matrix representing the configuration model
P = k*k'/sum(k);
% Compute the iterated square matrix
for r=1:20
  An = An^2;
  An = An/trace(An);
end
% Plot both the iterated square matrix and the configuration model. 
% They are both rank 1 matrices with the typical stripy pattern.
subplot(1,2,1); imagesc(An); subplot(1,2,2); imagesc(P);
```

Comment: What happens if the graph is disconnected, or is a cycle?

Comment: In case one has a disconnected graph the $A_\infty$ and $P$ differ, I restrict to connected graphs for the moment. 
In case of a cycle graph this relation is no longer true but nice things happen! 
When $N$ is even, $A_{\infty}$ has a checkerboard structure with alternating 0 and $1/N$ values. When $N$ is odd $2 A_{\infty} = P$ everywhere.
This must be related to the fact that the square matrix takes into consideration paths of length of powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

What you observe follows directly, I think, from the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).  The simplest form says that if $A$ is a matrix all of whose entries are non-negative such that some power of it $A^n$ has all *positive* entries, then $(A/\lambda)^n$ tends to a rank one matrix as $n$ grows, where $\lambda$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $A$.  Note that the condition  $A^n$ has all positive entries for some $n>0$ is equivalent to $A^{2^k}$ having all positive entries for some $k>0$, since $A^m$ having all positive entries implies $A^{m+1}$ does, too.

Comment: Very interesting, so the fact that in some cases this converges to the steady state distribution as in the configuration model $P$ has to searched in the spectral properties of the given network. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question here.  One can check the connectedness and aperiodicity of the graph without looking at the spectrum.  But in particular cases finding the dominant eigenvalue and finding the stationary distribution might require non-trivial computation.